# How I select only max-1 record?

Tags: sql-server

my question is "" I have 20 records and i want to retrieve 19th record which is max-1 suppose values are like from 1 to 20 so i want to retrieve 19th record which has value 19. Please help me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the nth row by selecting a specific row from a rownumber column temporary selection:

```
with Records AS 
(select row_number() over(order by datecreated) as 'row', * from myTable)
select * from Records where row=19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following query

```
SELECT TOP ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table)-1) * FROM Table
```